# No module named 'backports'

Tags: python, makefile, requirements.txt, backport

I am trying to build a python project using 'make build' command but getting below error while doing that. It was working earlier but starting throwing this error recently.

```
Collecting backports.zoneinfo (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
  Downloading https://<ARTIFACTORY_URL>/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-release/packages/packages/ad/85/475e514c3140937cf435954f78dedea1861aeab7662d11de232bdaa90655/backports.zoneinfo-0.2.1.tar.gz (74kB)
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-dcqnjb0t/backports.zoneinfo/setup.py", line 26, in <module>
        setuptools.setup(ext_modules=[c_extension])
      File "/usr/src/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 129, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 121, in setup
        dist.parse_config_files()
      File "/usr/src/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 494, in parse_config_files
        ignore_option_errors=ignore_option_errors)
      File "/usr/src/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 106, in parse_configuration
        meta.parse()
      File "/usr/src/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 382, in parse
        section_parser_method(section_options)
      File "/usr/src/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 355, in parse_section
        self[name] = value
      File "/usr/src/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 173, in __setitem__
        value = parser(value)
      File "/usr/src/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 430, in _parse_version
        version = self._parse_attr(value)
      File "/usr/src/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 305, in _parse_attr
        module = import_module(module_name)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'backports'
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-dcqnjb0t/backports.zoneinfo/
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 21.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

The package is downloaded when clicked on the artifactory link directly.

I tried installing the package separately using

```
pip install backports-zoneinfo
```

but still getting the same issue. The python version of venv is Python 3.8.8

Here is the requirements file:

```
gunicorn==19.9.0
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
backports.zoneinfo
flask
flake8
blinker==1.4
marshmallow==2.13.5
flasgger==0.9.2
pytest
firewall==1.1
sftpip==1.1
python-json-logger
pytest-cov
hvac
apscheduler
cryptography==2.2.2
```

pip list:

```
Package            Version
------------------ ----------
appdirs            1.4.4
APScheduler        3.7.0
asn1crypto         1.4.0
attrs              20.3.0
backports.weakref  1.0.post1
backports.zoneinfo 0.2.1
.....
```

Comment: @siso, any answer on this?  I have the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not manage to get this working, so I upgraded to python3.9. There `import zoneinfo` is enough...